# Ansible XML update

Tags: xml, ansible

I have an xml file which is created using ansible.  The output of the xml file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/6" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" />
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/5" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" />
</files>
```

I have an attribute `target_permission` created in this xml file. Now I need to split this into three. (`user_perm="6" grp_perm="0" oth_perm="0"`)

Is there a way in Ansible to do this?

```yaml
  - name: Update XML with file permissions mismatch
    xml:
     path: "{{output_file}}"
     xpath: /files/file
     attribute: user_perm
     value: 'target_permission | split[0:1]'  // I need something like this, what will be the syntax?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jinja allows using [Python methods](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#python-methods), yes you can slice a string like you would in pure Python:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      user_perm: {{ perm[0:1] }}
      grp_perm: {{ perm[1:2] }}
      oth_perm: {{ perm[2:] }}
  vars:
    perm: "600"
```

You could also go with the [list](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list) filter, as prompted in the documentation:

> If it was a string the returned list will be a list of characters.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      user_perm: {{ (perm | list)[0] }}
      grp_perm: {{ (perm | list)[1] }}
      oth_perm: {{ (perm | list)[2] }}
  vars:
    perm: "600"
```

Those two syntaxes both giving:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "user_perm: 6 grp_perm: 0 oth_perm: 0"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Now in order to change the existing nodes you have in your xml, you will have to make it in two steps, one to read the existing XML and the second one to fill in the `value`, as it is [a simple raw parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#parameter-value).

I would say that the best in your case would be to target, via `xpath`, the right XML element based on your `filename` attribute:

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no    
        
  tasks:
    - xml:
        path: xml.xml
        xpath: /files/file
        content: attribute
      register: xml
      
    - xml:
        path: xml.xml
        xpath: '/files/file[@filename="{{ item.file.filename }}"]'
        attribute: user_perm
        value: "{{ item.file.permission[0:1] }}"
      loop: "{{ xml.matches }}"
```

And your xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/6" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" />
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/5" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" />
</files>
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [xml] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [xml] **************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'file': {'filename': '/tmp/dir2/6', 'group': 'root', 'permission': '600', 'user': 'root', 'is_exists': 'True', 'target_permission': '600'}})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'file': {'filename': '/tmp/dir2/5', 'group': 'root', 'permission': '600', 'user': 'root', 'is_exists': 'True', 'target_permission': '600'}})

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And gives the resulting xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<files>
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/6" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" user_perm="6"/>
   <file filename="/tmp/dir2/5" group="root" permission="600" user="root" is_exists="True" target_permission="600" user_perm="6"/>
</files>
```

Just repeat this with the other attributes and you have your requested behaviour.

Comment: yes with normal ansible variable it is working, here target_permission is an xml attribute. I need to update the value field here.

Comment: Ok wasn't clear that you where also looking for that. Answer updated.

Comment: thank you, so looping is the only way right, we cannot use xml attribute directly as a variable.

Comment: At times permissions are listed as 1777, in this case value: "{{ item.file.permission[0:1] }}" behaves differently. How can i take 777? How to take last three digit for both cases?

Comment: You can also slice with negative indexes in Python. The negative index would be from the **end** of the string, as opposed to positive index that are from the beginning of it. So: `perm[-3:-2]`, `perm[-2:-1]` and `perm[-1:]` could work for this use case.

Comment: A double slicing could also do, but it seems over complcated: `perm[-3:][0:1]`,  `perm[-3:][1:2]` and `perm[-3:][2:]` makes it kind of fall back on the original solution